# New windows 10 installation stuck on "trying to connect to microsoft" & then"Looks like something happened."?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

ASUS VivoBook 15 i3

I have no internet on the laptop in question - it is an offline machine.

I do not want to link this laptop to a Microsoft account and all telemitry will be disabled once I get Windows installed.

I dont have internet or broadband at home, I tether to my iPhone as I get 5G which is more than fast enough for my needs. I am a home user so not a business and this laptop is for my 10 year old daughter to do her home work on (hence no internet for obvious reasons).

This laptop is brand new today, it came with Windows 11 but I dont like it or want it so I also purchased Windows 10 Pro.

The only thing that is attached to this laptop is the USB containg the Windows 10 Install and my wireless mouse dongle.

The problem happens whether my iPhones wi-fi hotspot is turned on or off and I have tried three different SSD's.

Using the Media Creation Tool, I downloaded Windows 10 Pro and created a Install USB.

I turned fast boot off in my BIOS (the install also fails with it enabled) and set the Boot Device to the USB.

I started the Win 10 install and when I was able, I deleted all of the partitions on the C: drive and created a new partition and formatted it  (in inside the windows install) .

When prompted, I entered my keyboard and other prefereneces when prompted and then it goes to "Checking the connection to Microsoft" and then after a whhile it changes to "Looks like something happened. Let's try reconnecting." and gets stuck there.

I have spent the last 12 hours trying all of the different suggestions on google, youtube and Et al. but none of them work, not a single one.

Comment: Have you tried in the "Let’s connect you to a network" screen, to press Shift+F10 to launch the Command Prompt and type the command `OOBE\BYPASSNRO` ?

Comment: What version of windows are you trying to install? Home or professional?

Comment: Shift+F10 will not launch the Cmd shell for me.

Comment: It is Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Dell Precision 7530 I bought second hand. If TL;DR go to THE SOLUTION down below.

Tried every tip I could gather on google, mostly on laptop manufacturer's and Microsoft's forums. I couldn't solve this puzzle. Every time I wanted to make a clean install of Win10, I got the "trying to connect to Microsoft" and then "something happened, reconnecting..." messages. You can bypass it either with the Ctrl+Shift+F3 combo to get the Admin login state with OOBE, or get a CMD with Shift+F10. After going through OOBE-reboot, I ended up with the "login to your XYZ company" screen. If I added a user it did not behave like a clean install first admin-rights user, that you can add on welcome screen. My Win10-debloat script was not running the same way, wasn't working properly.

I tried:

1. "Shift key while clicking Restart" to reset computer solution.
2. Permanently disabling Absolute/Computrace in BIOS.
3. Clearing all TMP 2.0 keys, then disabling TMP in BIOS.
4. Flashing BIOS with manufacturers official BIOS.
5. Switching out the SSD it came with.
6. And other tips.
   Nothing worked.

**THE SOLUTION** was, to put the laptop's SSD into another laptop (or PC), that doesn't have this issue. Install Win10 Pro N, to the point of creating first user after Welcome screen, boot into Windows, then shut it down. Put the SSD back to the problematic laptop, and eureka, it booted up properly. After connected to the internet, activation also worked by clicking Troubleshoot on Activation settings screen. And it used the laptop's own activation key, I did not need to use my own Win10 key. Debloat script executed as it used to.

Actually, it is not a solution, it is a workaround.